# How to install the fastlane using docker

Tags: docker

I have installed docker in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Now I need to install Fastlane. What is the way to install FastLane using the docker

Answer (score 0):

You can get the fastlane image with:

```
docker pull fastlanetools/fastlane
```

src: https://hub.docker.com/r/fastlanetools/fastlane/